# Drupal 7 Hook_forms not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, multiple-forms, hook-form

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

The drupal_render(drupal_get_form) is dynamically created in a foreach loop and put into a table theme.

Everything loads except the form fields. I've tried debugging by adding echos and exits to each form function call, but the page continues to load. I am not sure if these functions are simply not being called or if there is some other issue.

```
foreach( $w as $k => $v ) {
    $r[] = array(
        '$'.number_format($v->amount, 2),
        date('F d, Y', $v->created),
        filter_xss($v->paypal_email),
        drupal_render(drupal_get_form(('toefl_tutors_admin_withdrawl_request_form_'.$v->id), $v->id))
    );
}


function toefl_tutors_admin_withdrawl_request_forms($form_id, $args) {
    $forms = array();

    if (!empty($args) && $form_id == 'toefl_tutors_admin_withdrawl_request_form_' . $args[0]) {
        $forms[$form_id] = array(
            'callback' => 'toefl_tutors_admin_withdrawl_request_form',
            'callback arguments' => array($args[0]),
        );
    }

    return $forms;
}


function toefl_tutors_admin_withdrawl_request_form($form, &$form_state, $id = 0) {

    $form['twid'] = array(
        '#type'     => 'hidden',
        '#value'    => $id
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type'         => 'submit',
        '#value'        => t('Send Money'),
       '#attributes'    => array('class' => array('btn', 'btn-success'))
    );

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem.

I needed to rename the hook_forms function to toefl_tutors_forms() because My module name is actually toefl_tutors not toefl_tutors_admin_withdrawl_request

Apparently and correct me if I am wrong, in order to use hook_forms you must name it mymodulename_forms, not mymodulename_xx_forms.

What confused me was hook_form works perfectly when you name the form function mymodulename_xx_form().

Comment: Oh. I also needed to clear cache, after changing the name, as well.